# How do I output multiple lines to a file within a while loop?

Tags: bash, heredoc

I'm writing a Bash script and I'm trying to print out multiple lines of output and print them to a file. Here's what I've tried so far, this is just an example, but very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to print out "Hello World" to hello.txt every 2 seconds and be able to see hello.txt updated every 2 seconds. I would do this by running tail -f hello.txt. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
echo "Hello" >> hello.txt
echo "World" >> hello.txt
```

But I would need to run " >> hello.txt " after each line in my loop. So I learned to run the following to output a block of text to a file

```
cat >> hello.txt << EOL
echo "Hello"
echo "World"
EOL
```

Then I applied the while loop.

```
while true
do
    echo >> hello.txt << EOL
    echo "Hello"
    echo "World"
    EOL
    sleep 2
done
```

But then I got the following error.

```
./test.sh: line 10: warning: here-document at line 7 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOL')
./test.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Then I tried putting the file-output outside the while loop

```
echo >> hello.txt << EOL
while true
do
    echo "Hello"
    echo "World"
    sleep 2
done
EOL
```

But this printed out the actual code and not what it was intended to do. How can I print out multiple lines in a loop to a text file without having to write " >> hello.txt " after every line?

Comment: You can't indent the here-document or its end delimiter (`EOF` in your script), unless you use "`-`" (as in `<<-EOF`), in which case you can indent with tabs (but not spaces). Also, you don't use shell commands inside (like `echo`) inside a here-document, just the text you want to pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of a subshell

```
while true
do
    (
    echo "Hello"
    echo "World"
    ) >> hello.txt
    sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cat instead of echo.

```
while true
do
    cat << EOL >> hello.txt
Hello
World
EOL
    sleep 2                                                                     
done
```